# Rendering view with template in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

my webservice simple returnsd data below
say the url that return service be :http:/example/api/players.

> > > > [
> > > >                {
> > > >                   "id": 1,
> > > >                   "name": "Lily",
> > > >                   "age": 14,
> > > >                   "city": New York,
> > > >                },
> > > >                {
> > > >                  "id": 2,
> > > >                  "name": "BIlly",
> > > >                   "age": 14,
> > > >                   "city": New York,
> > > >               }
> > > >             ]

Can anybody provide me step by step examples to build html template to show list of players with proper template, view, model, collections for data above returned by webservice.

I looked through todomvc, and a lot of tutorails but couldnt figure out well.

it would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone.js Documentation is a great start.

Also be sure to check the [Hello Backbone.js](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/) tutorial and this excellent Envato Course (paid) [Get Connected to the Backbone](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/get-connected-to-the-backbone-new-course/)